# (MSAL) Issue with spanish characters getting name from social provider

Tags: javascript, facebook, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I'm having an issue using msal.js. I have a b2c tenant and when the user is logged I'm showing the user name, but if the name on the social provider(facebook or twitter) have an spanish character (ñ or accent) the name will be show with a strange character(for example ñ will be shown as Ã±) I debugged the call to getUser() on msal method and the name is with the strange characters.

```
var user = this.clientApplication.getUser(); //Msal.UserAgentApplication; object
user.name//this has the  Ã± character
```

Is this a bug on the js library or I'm missing something on b2c configuration?

Comment: Sounds like a standard character encoding problem ... Is your application using UTF-8 (and properly) …?

Comment: Yes, I'm using UTF-8 but using get user from the MSAL.js  I cant add the header to the request

Comment: I face the same problem whith MSAL.js and Azure AD B2C on a french character : "é". Have you solved it ?